# Mocha JS: running multiple test files: how to stop Mocha from lauching many Firefox instacnes at once?

Tags: node.js, selenium, testing, firefox, mocha.js

I'm having a problem with running test with Mocha.
I have 14 tests - each in one .js file. I want to run them one by one:

1. Open Firefox
2. Run the test
3. Close Firefox
4. Run new Firefox instance
5. Run the test
6. etc.

Problem is, when I execute "npm test" I'm getting 14 Firefox instances immediately opened. The test are running one by one (when one is running the other 13 instances are just open and waiting for the test tu end), but I don't want all instances at once.

Is there any solution for that?

OS: Windows 10
package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "Tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Tests XXX",
  "main": "xxx.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "firefox-profile": "^4.2.2",
    "mocha": "^9.2.2",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-rc-1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --sort --no-timeouts --reporter mochawesome --reporter-options reportFilename=TestResults"
  },
  "author": "mchodakowski",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Can you add a code example of a single test? In particular, what triggers the broswer to open during a the test run?

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that when `let driver = new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").setFirefoxOptions(options).build();` is inside `it`, then, there's no problem, but I've also wanted more than one `it` in one `describe`... in such case I would be forced to build `driver` in every `it` which is also not so convenient..

Comment: Did you try using mocha beforeAll hook as described here: https://mochajs.org/#root-hook-plugins ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't, thanks for the tip! I'll try it.